# Nested Gridview Footer Textbox Required Field Validation Firing for Each Row on Nested Gridview Footer Button Click

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the required field validation to fire only for the specific row when the add button is clicked.  But right now, when I click any add button, it fires the required field validation for all nested grid rows.  The code for the nested gridview and the image of the gridviews is the following.  I also tried to use validation groups, attempting to get unique validation groups for each nested gridview row, but couldn't get it to work.

[image]

```
<asp:GridView ID="GrdXML" runat="server" AllowSorting="false"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="0"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" onrowdeleting="GrdXML_RowDeleting" OnRowDataBound="OnRowDataBound"
    ShowFooter="false" CssClass="xmlgrid" OnSorting="GrdXML_Sorting" DataKeyNames="ContractRecordID">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract Start Date" SortExpression="ContractStartDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContractStartDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="30%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Contract End Date" SortExpression="ContractEndDate">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContractEndDate") %>'></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="50%" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractRecordID") %>' CommandName="Delete" 
                    onclick="BtnDelete_Click" Text="Delete" Width="60px" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="BtnDelete_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
                    runat="server" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Delete?" Enabled="True" 
                    TargetControlID="BtnDelete">
                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
            </ItemTemplate>
            <ItemStyle Width="40px" />
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit1" Text="<tr id='trGrid'><td colspan='100%'>" />
                <asp:GridView ID="projectCodeGridView" runat="server" AllowSorting="false" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="Horizontal" AutoGenerateColumns="false" ShowFooter="true" OnRowCommand="ProjectCodeGridView_RowCommand" OnRowCreated="ProjectCodeGridView_RowCreated" OnRowDataBound="ProjectCodeGridView_RowDataBound" OnRowDeleting="ProjectCodeGridView_RowDeleting" DataKeyNames="ContractProjectCodeID" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="0">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Project Codes" SortExpression="ContractProjectCode" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left">
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ContractProjectCode") %>' CssClass="projectcodelabel"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemStyle Width="100%" />
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox ID="projectCodeTextBox" runat="server" ValidationGroup='<%# "PC" + Eval("ContractProjectCodeID") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="projectCodeRequiredFieldValidator" runat="server" 
            ControlToValidate="projectCodeTextBox" ErrorMessage="Project Code Required" ForeColor="Red" Display="Static" ValidationGroup='<%# "PC" + Eval("ContractProjectCodeID") %>' Enabled="false"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle Width="100%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnDelete1" runat="server" 
                    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ContractProjectCodeID") %>' CommandName="Delete" 
                    onclick="BtnDelete1_Click" Text="Delete" Width="60px" />
                <ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender ID="BtnDelete1_ConfirmButtonExtender" 
                    runat="server" ConfirmText="Are you sure you want to Delete?" Enabled="True" 
                    TargetControlID="BtnDelete1">
                </ajaxToolkit:ConfirmButtonExtender>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                            <FooterTemplate>
                                <asp:Button ID="BtnAdd" runat="server" onclick="BtnAdd_Click" Text="Add" Width="60px" ValidationGroup='<%# "PC" + Eval("ContractProjectCodeID") %>' CommandName="Add" />
                            </FooterTemplate>
                            <FooterStyle Width="100%" />
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" Font-Bold="True" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="lit2" Text="</td></tr>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#999999" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" CssClass="padding" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#284775" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#F7F6F3" ForeColor="#333333" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="padding" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#E2DED6" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#506C8C" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6F8DAE" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: Is the ContractProjectCodeID unique for each row?

Comment: That pointed me in the right direction. Thanks! If you post an answer, I can mark it as the accepted answer. @KiranHegde

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the validation control of each row you are adding the ValidationGroup='<%# "PC" + Eval("ContractProjectCodeID") %>'. As you are saying, that the validation triggers for the wrong row, it could be that ContractProjectCodeID may not be unique for each row. I think what you can do is add row index to the validation group

```
ValidationGroup='<%# "PC" + Container.DataItemIndex + Eval("ContractProjectCodeID")
```